# Нужна ли запятая (правило для того чтобы)

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая во втором случае?

1) Для того чтобы просмотреть информацию, необходимо зарегистрироваться на сайте.

2) Для того чтобы просмотреть информацию(,) необходимо:
1. перейти на сайт;
2. зарегистрироваться...

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, т. к. в обоих случаях запятая отделяет придаточное от главного.